# Performance testing ArrayList in C#

Tags: c#, performance, insert, arraylist, performance-testing

I want to do a performance test on how fast an ArrayList(System.Collections - C#) can insert an item at the beginning.

I've opened a file for reading lines of data from, set up a Stopwatch and also created an ArrayList to add items to(as follows):

```
Stopwatch watchTime = new Stopwatch();
Double totalTime = 0; 
using (StreamReader readText = new StreamReader("data.txt"))
{
    String line;
    Int32 counter = 0; 
    while ((line = readText.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    }
}
```

I use the counter to keep track of how many items i'm entering into the ArrayList.

Within the while loop i have the following:

```
watchTime.Start();
theList.Insert(0, line);
watchTime.Stop();
Double time = watchTime.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
totalTime = totalTime + time; 
Console.WriteLine(time);
watchTime.Reset();
++counter;
```

Is this a correct way of checking how fast inserting items into the beginning of the ArrayList occurs??

I made another program that does the exact same thing - however using a Dictionary. To my surprise, the time it takes for this ArrayList to insert items is much longer than the amount of time the Dictionary takes. Why is this happening?

Comment: You could fire up a performance profiler like [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) and see where the performance is going into.

Comment: Why measure `ArrayList`. It's been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Henk sorry, could you explain to me why this would be the case? The stopwatch is surrounding the insertion only - not anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I would suggest:

- Don't use files to get input. Why introduce IO into the system?
- Instead of repeatedly stopping and starting the stopwatch, just insert lots of lines into the `ArrayList` without doing anything else. Time that big loop in one go.

As for why `Dictionary<,>` is cheaper - you didn't show any code, but basically your insertion code will have to copy the entire contents of the `ArrayList` on every insertion. `ArrayList` maintains an array to hold the contents of the list. Usually the array is larger than the list - when you add an element at the end, if can just assign the new value into the right bit of the array. If you insert it elsewhere, it has to copy elements of the array to "make room" for the new element.

You'd find it a lot quicker adding at the end. `Dictionary<,>` uses a completely different data structure; it has to resize at some points, but it will have very different characteristics in general.

(I would suggest you use `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList` to start with, and if you want a collection you can insert at the start of repeatedly, consider a `LinkedList<T>` - or possibly a queue or stack, depending on what you want to do with it later.)

Comment: thanks, reading this was actually quite helpful in explaining why i see the ArrayList taking so much time just to insert something at the beginning. I actually want to performance test an ArrayList vs a Dictionary just to understand how it's working and why one might be slower than the other when inserting in different places...  Thanks for your response - very helpful.

Comment: @BlueButtons: It's worth understanding that while a list is ordered, a dictionary isn't - you don't really insert into a "place" in a dictionary, you just map a key to a value.

Comment: @ Jon would this mean that the type of key you have (ie int or string) would also effect the rate at which an insertion occurs while using a Dictionary? I'm guessing it would.

Comment: @ Jon btw, cool website. I'll be browsing through your new and old site. Seems you have a lot of good knowledge to offer.

Comment: @BlueButtons: To some extent, in that it has to take the hash as well. But you'd rarely want to decide between a list or a dictionary - they serve different purposes. If you want an ordered list, use a list. If you want an arbitrary mapping, use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Too much complex. Read the file "normally" in a list appending at the end and then benchmark adding the first list to the second. Otherwise you are trying to benchmark too many small actions, and you get precision problems.

Some code

```
ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();

using (StreamReader readText = new StreamReader("data.txt"))
{
    String line;
    Int32 counter = 0; 
    while ((line = readText.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        tempList.Add(line);
    }
}

ArrayList theList = new ArrayList();

Stopwatch watchTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();

foreach (string line in tempList)
{
    theList.Insert(0, line);
}

watchTime.Stop();
```

I'll add that with `Stopwatch` you can `Start`, `Stop` and then `Start` again and it will continue keeping the time. To reset it, there is another method, `Restart`.

As other have probably suggested:

- Use `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList` (the speed is the same, but `List<string>` is type safe)
- In general, if you only have to insert elements at the head of the Lists, insert them at the tail (much faster) and "reverse" the index (so index `0` is index `Count - 1`, 1 is `Count - 2` and so on). Lists aren't "made" for "in the middle" or "at the top" insertion. They are made for "add last".

Comment: Why bother reading in the lines at all, if the only aim is to benchmark `ArrayList.Insert`? Just insert the same string reference multiple times.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try this out and see what type of results i get. Thanks for the response, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @JonSkeet He read the file to know how many strings there are :-) I thought he had to read a file, not that he wanted to see how much O(n) slow is ArrayList just for the sake of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet In the end you are right, if he is only want to find the speed of inserting a reference to the head of an ArrayList and measure the decaying speed of this insertion.